# Iterate String[] in anonymous runnable (Android Service)

Tags: android, storage, android-service, runnable

I'm trying to figure out a good way to give my services a preference file, like the SavedInstanceState of an activity.  This service starts, sets an alarm, and calls stopSelf();, because it may be days before it runs again, I want it to start, do its task, then be done.  I'm just going to same some key/value pairs in a comma separated text file.

OK, so I want to open the FileInputStream provided by Context, but I have to handle the exception.  I'd rather check to be sure the file exists first to avoid the error, and in case a large list of files is returned I want to do this work off the UI thread.  Here is my code:

```
public void setNewAlarm() {
    Log.d("alarmServ", "inside setNewAlarm()");

    FileInputStream fis;
    Time time = new Time();
    Boolean prefsAvail = false;
    String[] fileList = fileList();

    Runnable fileCheck = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            int i = 0;
            while (i<fileList.length) {
                if (fileList[i] == "preferences") {
                    prefsAvail = true;
                    break;
                }
                i++;
            }
            if (prefsAvail) {
                try {
                    fis = openFileInput("preferences");
                } catch (FileNotFoundException ioe) {
                    Log.d("alarmServ", "i/o error: output file fail");
                    ioe.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    };

    //do something with the InputStream - read prefs and build alarm based on the criteria
}
```

The problem then, obviously, is the FileInputStream, boolean, and String[] are not available inside the runnable.  How can I work around this, my understanding was that nested classes had access to their container's variables.  Is this not true because its declared inside a method?

I tried googling, and discovered that one way to do this would be to declare the data as final, but this doesn't seem appropriate for a boolean or the stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need just to save key/value pairs I would suggest you using [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref), this is a preferred Android way.

Also if you intended to use files I would suggest you just to run it on the worker thread, that way you won't need to share your FileInputStream, boolean, and String[] between threads.

P.S. to use reference inside anonymous inner class, you have to define it as `final`.

Comment: All 3 questions answered.  I didn't realize I could use SharedPreferences in a service, I have been using them in Activity.  I kind of went this way to learn from the attempt as well, good idea to just do everything inside the thread.  I declared the reference in the main class body outside of all methods, and didnt' have to declare them as final for some reason, but the above code is working and returning useful results.

Comment: Glad it helped :) Ofcourse, when you just declare field you can always use it inside inner class, because inner class contains reference to the outer class. You have to declare `final` only local variables inside method to use them inside inner class.